# pgAdmin list of keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, postgresql, pgadmin

I've been using pgAdmin for several days and so far I like it. However, I can't find a list of keyboard shortcuts documented anywhere, either on the pgAdmin site, in the help, or in the options menu.

I stumbled into one myself that is nowhere in the menu hierarchy, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to execute SQL, so there has to be a list somewhere (hopefully not just in the source code).

Is there a list of keyboard shortcuts somewhere I haven't looked?

Comment: The pgAdmin III site contains the information, please look at [https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/query.html](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/query.html)

Answer (score 14):

I didn't find a list, but I'm using the following shortcuts often:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - Show table data
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> - Filter

Anyway there are some Query tool's shortcuts [here](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/query.html)

Answer (score 6):

The most important is the <kbd>F5</kbd> key to run the selected SQL code.

You can also select multiple lines and use <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to mess with the indentation.

Here are some more shortcut keys:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to comment out the selected text or current line (prefix with "-- ")
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to remove comment indication (remove the "-- " at the start of the lines)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> convert to uppercase
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> convert to lowercase

Comment: It's Ctrl+K to comment and Shift+Ctrl+K to uncomment. The same for Upper (Ctrl+U) and lower (Shift+Ctrl+U).

Comment: Cntrl+Shift+U to toggle between uppercase and lowercase.

Answer (score 5):

You would normally use <kbd>F5</kbd> to execute a query in the SQL editor.
To be precise, this executes the selected part or the whole content of the window if nothing is selected.

Other than that, you should find almost all shortcuts in the respective menu right beside the command.